# Bokeh dropdown showing improper values

Tags: bokeh

I'm populating the Bokeh dropdown menu from a list of values and showing the output in two ways: An HTML file, and in a local app through the command line (`bokeh serve --show myapp_3.py`)

When doing the HTML output the dropdown properly shows the correct values, but when I run the same exact code with the app, the values look like they are from an older run and aren't the ones being passed to the menu.

What would cause the dropdown values to persist from an older run or not update properly when running the code through the command prompt?
It still happens when I rename the .py file.

It it helps, this is how I'm populating the dropdown:

```
optionslist=list(dataframe["Values"])

menu= Select(options=optionslist,value="",title="DropDown")
layout=column(menu,p)

def callback(attr, old, new):
        source.data={'x':data_x, 'y':data_y}
menu.on_change('value', callback)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Other changes (like removing the dropdown completly) are correctly shown via the bokeh server?

Comment: Yes, everything you mentioned works well but I have no idea why the values in the server version are entirely different.

Comment: I realized that the code run for the HTML output and the server was creating a different output and the dropdown was using that. Thank you for your help

Comment: If  you think others might benefit from your solution, you can write an answer and accept it.